# HTML5 Phonegap Android App - Open external URLs within app?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Currently in the process of building a HTML5/Jquery mobile shop Phonegap compiled Android App.

We need to process our orders by sending a URL to an external https webpage.  Is it possible to open this page within our app rather that externally in the phones browser?

The external page contains a simple form - the user needs to enter a email and code into it and once submitted the page will return an encoded URL to the app.

I have seen this process several times in other apps, but have no idea how to approach it. Can anyone help?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is, just use a WebView for this, implement your own WebViewClient to handle the clicks. This way you can handle links either internally or send them to the phone's browser. Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

The Javadoc of the WebView has some samples on how to use it.

Comment: Cheers for your help - that looks interesting, i'm new to Android app building though - so how would you include a call to Webview within a HTML5 page?

Comment: Are you wrapping your HTML5 pages into an android app? So, you already use a WebView right?

Comment: I'm using Phonegap to compile the html5/jqeurymobile/css into an app if thats what you mean?  cheers for your help by the way.. Paul

Comment: Ah, yes, so you already use a WebView, as this is used to wrap html content into an app. So you need to add a webview client to this webview and tell this webview client to handle the url internally. But the default WebViewClient already handles all URLs internally. So I think, phonegap registers an own client which sends all external links to the phones browser by default. Maybe you should retag your question with "phonegap" and state more clearly that your app is a phonegap app.

Comment: Cheers Hefner -  Will do!  Paul

Answer (score 1):

It is best to not load any new HTML pages in your app. If you need the equivalent of a new screen, add a hidden div to your page with `display:none`, hide the other divs, then make the new div visible with `display:block`. For transactions with your web server try to use only XHR. This is a little bit like loading a page in an iframe except that you have more control over it and you can even leverage the Phonegap API if needed.

Answer (score 1):

What I personally use is a PhoneGap plugin called [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android) which exists also for iOS.
This plugin allows you to open an ADDITIONAL WebView as a modal dialog INSIDE your PhoneGap app! It's used for example in FaceBook login, I use it to show Files without leaving my app.
Once the user is done and closes the dialog he's back in your app (he actually never left it), solving the issue for iOS users on "how to get back to the app"...

Hope this helps

Comment: i recently tried using ChildBrowser and it works fine. is there a way through which i can show a loading/wait message until the page gets loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the external Website via an iFrame in your WebView.